# How do I make my lists go under the paragraphs and float alongside my image?

Tags: html, css

This is my [HTML](http://pastebin.com/Tyk5DMm7) and my [CSS](http://pastebin.com/ab5m0Gg8).

I was going to post just a snippet of the code but when I tested just the code itself everything was fine with my lists.

For some reason my 2nd paragraph is able to float alongside my 2nd image, but the list won't and just goes in between the 1st image and paragraph [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ3BV.jpg). I want them to be under the 2nd paragraph and alongside my 2nd image. How can I fix this?

Comment: As like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/uveLt3wg/

Comment: Thank you, that's better. But is it possible for the list to be on the right hand side of the image right under the paragraph?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/uveLt3wg/3/ cehck to this

Comment: Please learn how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then paste just the relevant code in your question, rather than using a third-party site and forcing anyone who wants to help to go look up your code elsewhere.

Comment: Thankyou! I would mark you as best comment but it seems i can't for small comments under my post whereas i can for big comments.